# Hiding Dependencies Using CMake Lists

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies

A snippet of my system looks like so:

http://i67.tinypic.com/ml5dmt.png

I wish to hide the app's Tensorflow and Protobuf A dependencies from the user program. Otherwise, there are symbol clashes between the 2 different Protobuf versions (A and B are different versions) when trying to build the system as both are visible to the user program.

Comment: It is a **bad idea** to have one program linked with two *different versions* of the same dynamic library. You may try to build `Protobuf A` statically and compile it into your library.

Comment: Both tensorflow and protobuf are available in the cmake dependency manager called Hunter (github.com/ruslo/hunter). Hunter ensures that the correct versions of all libraries and their dependencies are built for your project and (by default) statically linked.